# PHP/PDO - Check if URL contains a particular list of domains

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a list of domains in an array e.g.

```
$notAllowedWebsites = array('google.com','yahoo.com','facebook.com');
```

Now I have a MySQL database that contains a column full of urls e.g.

1. facebook.com/testpage
2. google.com/search
3. bbc.co.uk/news/going-to-the-sea
4. ft.com/big-success
5. google.com/time

Now I want to extract the above URLS from the above table where the domains exist in the url. In other words I want to extract:
 1. facebook.com/testpage
 2. google.com/search
 3. google.com/time

This is my code:

```
foreach($notAllowedWebsite as $notAllowedWebsite){
    $sqlQueryBusinessWebsite = $dbh->prepare("SELECT business_website FROM client_table WHERE business_website = :business_website");
    $sqlQueryBusinessWebsite->execute(array(':business_website'=>$notAllowedWebsite));
    $sqlResultBusinessWebsite = $sqlQueryBusinessWebsite->fetch();
    $businessWebsiteDB = $sqlResultBusinessWebsite['business_website'];
}
```

I'm not sure how I'm going to modify this line `$sqlQueryBusinessWebsite = $dbh->prepare("SELECT business_website FROM client_table WHERE business_website = :business_website");` to check whether the domain exists in the url.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried LIKE clause ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement it in my above PDO code

Comment: Use IN clause without use of foreach loop acheck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: Is the list of banned/not allowed websites in the database or within code? If it's in the database it would be A LOT easier to manage?

Comment: Actually it is in a database I used the array in my question to simply my question.

Comment: @user6043723 - I've added an answer that may help?

Comment: @Gavin. I think I found my problem. My array is actually values stored in my database. On the outter set I have a mysql function that lists all the "blocked websites". Then I'm trying to call the MySQL code. My problem seems to be in this line - `$sqlResultBusinessWebsite = $sqlQueryBusinessWebsite->fetch();` It doesn't seem to be outputting anything.

Comment: @user6043723 - Most likely because the query is expecting an exact match. You would need to use a like and if there is more than one result, you'll need to loop. The solution I've provided will output a list of values where the domain exists in the business_website column. This way you only need to process the results, not loop through and query every single domain.

Answer (score 0):

use the LIKE clause:

```
foreach($notAllowedWebsite as $notAllowedWebsite){
    $sqlQueryBusinessWebsite = $dbh->prepare("SELECT business_website FROM client_table WHERE business_website LIKE :business_website");
    $sqlQueryBusinessWebsite->execute(array(':business_website'=>'%'.$notAllowedWebsite.'%'));
    $sqlResultBusinessWebsite = $sqlQueryBusinessWebsite->fetch();
    $businessWebsiteDB = $sqlResultBusinessWebsite['business_website'];
}
```

Comment: are you sure the database values start with google.com, yahoo.com? and nothing before?

Comment: Yes they are.Thanks.

Comment: Ah that's probably why, try it now, I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Regular Expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) would be the best solution here

```
SELECT business_website FROM business_website WHERE business_website RLIKE '(?=.*facebook)(?=.*yahoo)'
```

Comment: I have hundreds of urls that is why I'm using an array.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm sure there is a cleaner way, the following will get all sites that contain a domain from the banned list:

```
CREATE TABLE `banned_sites` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `domain` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `entries` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `website` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

insert into banned_sites (domain) values ('facebook.com'), ('yahoo.com'), ('google.com');
insert into entries (website) values ('http://www.facebook.com/thisisatest'), ('http://www.msn.com'), ('http://google.com'), ('yahoo.com');
```

Then you can do:

```
select e.* from entries e inner join banned_sites bs on (e.website like concat('%', concat(bs.domain, '%')))
```

SQLFiddle isn't working at the moment, otherwise I'd show you it working.